# Implementing a Python-like List in C++

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic, data-structures, types

The answer to this almost certainly exists elsewhere I just can't come up with the words for this, please feel free to direct me to other resources.

I am looking to implement a Python-esque list in C++. I **do not** mean I want to create a `vector`. I know how that is done. What I am looking to do is create a data structure that could store values such as:

```
[1, "a", 3.5]
```

like in Python. I also want it to be dynamic in size.

Is there a name for this? Is this already implemented somewhere?

I have been experimenting with a linked list that contains templated nodes, but I don't know how to write the accessing function which will get node `i` when node `i` will have potentially *any* data type. Thoughts, suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like a `std::tuple` actually, rather than a `std::vector`, unless you're considering a [`std::vector<std::any>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::vector<std::any>` is like what I'm looking for but is there a solution to this that isn't C++17?

Comment: `std::vector<boost::any>`

Comment: @Fireho do you know where I can find the source for `boost::any`?

Comment: @NickChapman Well, from a `boost` library provider. Just Google it, you'll have to find out how to do it eventually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> like in Python. I also want it to be dynamic in size.

Well, for fixed sizes a [`std::tuple<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) should serve you well.

> Is there a name for this? Is this already implemented somewhere?

The *"name for this"* is, a ***container serving to store an arbitrary sequence of types with dynamic size***. Though the focus is on the ***arbitrary type*** placeholder.

Unfortunately there's no [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) type in the current standard, that supports dynamically sized containers like `std::vector<std::any>`.

If you don't have access to an experimental [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) implementation with your toolchain, you might be able to use the [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any.html) type.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `vector` of `any`.  The `any` type comes in boost or C++17.